# How to extract Image URL from Post via Tweepy and Twitter API v2?

Tags: twitter, tweepy

I am trying to extract an image URL from an X post to no avail.
I have basic level access.

Here is my code and what I have tried:

```
import tweepy
from secret_variables import bearer_token

specified_accounts = '@random_X_account'

client = tweepy.Client(bearer_token=bearer_token)

account_query = f'from:{specified_account[1:]} -is:retweet -is:reply'
tweet_fields = ["text"]
media_fields = ["media_key","preview_image_url","url"]
response = client.search_recent_tweets(account_query,
    tweet_fields=tweet_fields,
    expansions=['attachments.media_keys'],
    media_fields=media_fields,
    max_results=10)
tweets = response.data # for further use in the code
includes = response.includes # for further use in the code

print(f'responses is {response}')
```

The (shortened) output I get is:

```
responses is Response(data=[<Tweet id=1699365344446382377 text='New York, New York. https://twitter.com/earthcurated/status/1699365344446382377'>, <Tweet id=1699108063465087038 text='Ocean Sunset  https://twitter.com/earthcurated/status/1699108063465087038'>,...], includes={'media': [<Media media_key=3_1699365331649662976 type=photo>, <Media media_key=3_1699047441486491648 type=photo>,...]}, errors=[], meta={'newest_id': '16994395XXXXXXX2251', 'oldest_id': '169862XXXXXX42925', 'result_count': 10, 'next_token': 'XXXXXXX'})
```

I have checked out these ressources:
https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/tweets/search/api-reference/get-tweets-search-recent
https://docs.tweepy.org/en/stable/expansions_and_fields.html#media-fields
https://docs.tweepy.org/en/stable/client.html#search-tweets

So, unfortunately there are no image urls in my includes although I checked and the posts have one each. I don't know what (or if something) is wrong.

Help is very much appreciated.